# Remove background

Tags: plotting

I am using `ListDensityPlot` and get for example the following map (random data). 
I would like to remove the same Intensity background value for all the point in data[[3]].
I was thinking to use the following line : `dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]]-Background value}` instead of `dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]]}` But I don't see any difference after the substraction...

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[100, {20, 3}];
dataT = Transpose[data];
dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]]}; 
dataT[[3]] = Rescale[dataT[[3]], MinMax[dataT[[3]]], {-1., 1.}];
data = Transpose[dataT];

graph = ListDensityPlot[data,
  PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {-1., 1.}}]
```

Comment: try `ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {-1., 1.}}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#3 > backgroundvalue &)]` or subtract `backgroundvalue` after you rescale `dataT[[3]]`?

Comment: thanks, `RegionFunction` works but how can I combine two area `RegionFunction -> (-1 < #3 < 0 &)` + `RegionFunction -> (0.5 < #3 < 1 &)` in `ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {-1., 1.}}, RegionFunction -> (#3 > backgroundvalue &)]`

Comment: does `RegionFunction -> (Or[-1 < #3 < 0, 0.5 < #3 < 1] &)` work?

Comment: seems to be. Thanks

Comment: Bigprophete, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ListDensityPlot[data, 
  PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {-1., 1.}}, 
  RegionFunction -> (Or[-1 < #3 < 0, 0.5 < #3 < 1] &)]
```

[image]